# Parsing a paragraph of info from HTML page in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get my head around regex in more detail..

I am trying to extract each paragraph in the following html page:

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Use [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/), don't waste your time trying to come up with a fragile home-brew parser.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at pQuery (it's a Perl port to jQUery) and I found it extremely useful.

Comment: [HTML::Query](http://p3rl.org/HTML::Query) and [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web::Query) are better.